# no mssql-jdbc auth-8.4.1.x64 in java.library.path on linux

Tags: java, mssql-jdbc, java.library.path, integrated-security

I am trying to use the SQL Server integratedSecurity (`jdbc: sqlserver: //x.y.z.w; databaseName = TEST; integratedSecurity = true`) with java 1.8 on Linux but I get the following error:
*no mssql-jdbc auth-8.4.1.x64 in java.library.path*

All my research led to having to add a dll (which obviously doesn't make sense on linux) inside the java bin directory.
Can you confirm that integratedSecurity does not work on linux? Or am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Just found that there is no AD support for mssql driver on linux platform. Recommendation is to use JTDS driver.